# Pull On/Onto Top Of

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Suppose I am standing on the roof of a house.  I pulled on one end of a rope, the other end of which is tied to a box.  The box is raised from the ground as I pulled the rope until the box is on the rooftop:

> 1. I pulled the box ***onto*** top of the roof.
> 2. I pulled the box on ***top*** of the roof.

Is the "*on*" in sentence 2  wrong because the verb "*pull*" does not have the "*to*" sense.  So, "*onto*" should be used instead?

Comment: Your #1 example seems to need the "the" for "the top of the roof" due to the presence of "to": e.g. *"I pulled the box **to the top** of the roof"*, and *"I pulled the box **on to the top** of the roof"*, and *"I pulled the box **onto the top** of the roof"*.

Comment: I wouldn't say either of those. I'd say "I pulled the box onto the roof", "I pulled the box up to the roof", or maybe "I pulled the box up to the rooftop".

Comment: As Begin says, "on(to) the roof" almost invariably means on to the top of the roof. A roof technically has 2 sides and you might attach something underneath, but you would have to specify "underneath the roof" "to the bottom of the roof", or say "ceiling".

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, 'on' and 'onto' both can be used. However, what I suggest is when you have some 'movement' involved, 'onto' **may** work better (however, 'on' is **not** incorrect). On the other hand, when the movement is **not** there, using 'on' is preferred over 'onto'.

So, in your example, the movement is involved as you are pulling the box.

> I pulled the box onto the top of the roof *(notice the article you missed)

As I said, using 'on' there does **not** make the sentence ungrammatical.